# how to build feature with complex attributes using geotools?

Tags: java, geotools

I'd like to build a feature type and then a feature itself that is composed of complex attributes. I assume I could do this like that:

```
final SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
builder.add("geometry", com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry.class);
builder.add("id", String.class);
builder.add("attribute", MyComplexAttribute.class);
```

But... I have a dynamic model description and I don't have any class that represents this complex attribute.. is it possible to build it some different way? I'd be grateful for a code examples for both FeatureType building and Feature.

Comment: what about Object? `builder.add("attribute", Object.class);`

Comment: tried that already, for now I found a workaround to generate classes in the runtime using cglib but still I feel this is more a hack than a proper solution `Object myBean = beanGenerator.create();
        builder.add("myComplex", myBean.getClass());`